# Openssl command to Java or Loading Pem with encrypted key and cert into keystore

Tags: java, openssl, bouncycastle, pem, pkcs#12

I am looking to convert this command to java so that i can convert a pem file to the p12 format to be used in the application key store:
`openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey combinedCertAndKey.pem -in combinedCertAndKey.pem -out cert_key.p12`

The file contains an encrypted private key.  I have been playing around with examples from here and other places but most have deprecated classes or class cast issues, i was trying to use the latest bouncycastle libs - 1.76 but i cant find working examples on this version and i really dont know it well at all.

If I run this command manually and use the p12 it works, but this has to be dynamic in the sense a pem will be stored securely(cant be binary), my springboot application will then access it in a secure manner, load this pem into memory and must then load it into the applications keystore. I figured if i can convert this command to java i would be sorted but there might be a simpler better solution?

Is this conversion possible and are there better approaches, maybe i dont need to do any conversion but instead read the keys directly into the keystore?  I want to use as little 3rd party libraries as is possible.